# Recover contacts with old country code, new iPhone in a new country

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, sim

I just bought a new iPhone, with iOS 15 after *moving to another country*. But after getting a **new SIM** and **transferring all** the data, the countries area codes got messed up.

I have the old contacts in the old country configuration 09XXXXXXXXXXX

In my new country, I use a local cell number, and they are 06XXXXXXXXX.

However I found out that the **contacts of my last country** did not get the new area code of the country, just a few of them. Therefore I have to manually set up the numbers again, and I have many numbers that I don't want to loose.

It is annoying, because most of my contacts are now messed up, and in WhatsApp more than half of my friends appear as unknown numbers. Now I cannot contact them properly.

Is there an smarter way to fix it, rather than manually changing the country codes?